# How to change colors in Primefaces chart?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have several questions how to improve this Primefaces chart.

[image]

This is the source code:

```
<h:form>

<p:barChart id="basic" value="#{DashboardController.categoryModel}" legendPosition="ne"  
            title="Accounts and Groups" min="0" max="200" style="height:400px"
            shadow="true" barPadding="60"/>  

</h:form>
```

```java
import org.primefaces.model.chart.CartesianChartModel;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.ChartSeries;

@Named("DashboardController")
@SessionScoped
public class Dashboard implements Serializable
{

    /*
     * Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver
     */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;
    private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;

    public Dashboard()
    {
        createCategoryModel();
    }

    public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel()
    {
        return categoryModel;
    }

    private void createCategoryModel()
    {
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();

        // Active Accounts

        ChartSeries ActiveAccounts = new ChartSeries();
        ActiveAccounts.setLabel("Active Accounts");

        ActiveAccounts.set("Active Accounts", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(ActiveAccounts);

        // Blocked Accounts

        ChartSeries BlockedAccounts = new ChartSeries();
        BlockedAccounts.setLabel("Blocked Accounts");

        BlockedAccounts.set("Blocked Accounts", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(BlockedAccounts);

        // Active Groups

        ChartSeries ActiveGroups = new ChartSeries();
        ActiveGroups.setLabel("Active Groups");

        ActiveGroups.set("Active Groups", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(ActiveGroups);

        // Blocked Groups

        ChartSeries BlockedGroups = new ChartSeries();
        BlockedGroups.setLabel("Blocked Groups");

        BlockedGroups.set("Blocked Groups", 120);

        categoryModel.addSeries(BlockedGroups);



    }
}
```

Can you tell me how I can change the color of the chart size, also the color of "Accounts and Groups"?
I also want to ask you how I can add names below every column? Now I have only one name "Active Accounts". I want to name the columns individually.

Best wishes

P.S I tested this code into the JSF header but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/css">
        .jqplot-title{
        color:red;
        }
    </script>
```

P.S 2 Only the label of the chart is changed

[image]

Comment: try 2 replace the `<script` with `style `  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp

Comment: yes, only the title of the chart is changed. How I can change the numbers on the left?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `seriesColors` attribute of `<p:barChart`

like this `seriesColors="000000, FFFFFF, 2288AA"`

about the title and the axis color, use this:

```
.jqplot-title{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.jqplot-xaxis-label{
    color: #FF0000; 
}
.jqplot-yaxis-label{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this changes the color of the columns, not the describing text.

Comment: did you tried the new jqplot-xaxis-label and jqplot-yaxis-label too ? cause i donty see it in your new posted code

Comment: Yes, I added the code - this is the latest code that I tested: http://pastebin.com/pkMAwpMX

Comment: This changes the label at the bottom: `.jqplot-xaxis-tick{
                color:#FFFFFF;
            }` But I can't find how to change the `jqplot-yaxis-label`.