# How to change fontSize of a legend in p:chart

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I have a problem trying to resize the legend of a graph in PRIMEFACES CHART I tried using the **this.cfg.legend** configuration with the **fontSize** property but I can not change the size of the letters.

I'm using a **outputscript** and in **managedbean** I'm calling it with **setExtender**. The version of PRIMEFACES that I am using is 5.3.

Image of help: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thYDT.png)

**OutputScript** code:

```
< h:outputScript >
  function chartExtender1() 
  {
    this.cfg.grid 
    = { 
         background: '#BBDEFB',
         gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
         borderColor: '#999999',
         borderWidth: 5.0,
         shadow: false,
      };
    this.cfg.legend 
    = {               
        show : false,
        show : true,
        border : 'none',
        location : 's',
        fontSize: '10px',
        fontFamily: ["Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Arial","Verdana","sans-serif"],            
        placement : 'outsideGrid',
        renderer : $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,                
        rendererOptions : 
           {
            numberRows : 4,
            numberColumns : 4,
            seriesToggle : true,
            disableIEFading : true
           }  
          };
    }                     
 < /h:outputScript >
```

ManagedBean code:

```
LineadateModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
LineadateModel.setExtender("chartExtender");               
LineadateModel.setSeriesColors("1565C0, FF6F00, FFEA00, 558B2F, 651FFF");
LineadateModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Usados");
LineadateModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setTickCount(3);
LineadateModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMax(MaximoValorY );
DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Hora");
axis.setTickAngle(-50);
axis.setMax(horamax);    
axis.setTickFormat("%H:%#M");
axis.setTickCount(20);
LineadateModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
```

Create the chart:

 `< p:chart class="fondo" type="line" model="#{PrincipalPosicion1.lineaDateModel}" responsive="true"/>`

I checked but it did not work:

[How to change colors in Primefaces chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612558/how-to-change-colors-in-primefaces-chart)

[How to change Bar Charts Legend position in PrimeFaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883948/how-to-change-bar-charts-legend-position-in-primefaces)

Thanks for the help

Comment: how about using css? say overload the `.jqplot-table-legend` css class? to maybe: `.jqplot-table-legend { font-size: 16px }`

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Effectively in CSS I solved the problem.


.jqplot-table-legend
{    
    font-size: 9px;
}


Greetings.